# Calculate transportation count for is_rail,is_road & is_air

Tags: plsql

Create a Function named 'find_port' which takes port id(i.e, p_id) as input and returns the count of transportation(i.e, transportation_count') that could be made using that port.

**Function name** : find_port

**Input Parameter** : p_id in int

**Output variable** : transportation_count variable of type number

**Design rules:**

1) If is_rail of the given port id is 'True',then display the transportation_count as '1'.
2) If is_rail of the given port id is 'False',then display the transportation_count as '0'.
(NOTE :Design rule is only for example. Calculate transportation count for is_rail,is_road & is_air.)

Refer to the schema for port details.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ7ZO.png)

As a solution I have used the following query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_port(p_id in NUMBER)
  RETURN varchar2
IS 
  transportation_count varchar2(10);
BEGIN
  SELECT is_rail INTO transportation_count  FROM port WHERE port.id=p_id;

  IF transportation_count = 'True' THEN
    transportation_count := '1';
  ELSE
    transportation_count := '0';
  END IF;

  RETURN transportation_count;
END;
```

But this is only giving result for is_rail. Can anyone please tell me how to get the count from is_road & is_air.

Comment: May be bitmask need to be used? You got 2 states on 3 properties that can be masked only in 3^2=9 number values

Answer (score 0):

is that what you need?

```
declare
  is_rail varchar2(10);
  is_road varchar2(10);
  is_air varchar2(10);
begin
....
  SELECT is_rail
       , is_road
       , is_air 
  INTO is_rail
     , is_road
     , is_air
  FROM port WHERE port.id=p_id;
...
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need plsql as it can be done in a single sql statement. Sql does not contain the "IF" statement but does contain a "CASE" statement. Just use that on each of the three columns.

```
with port (id, country,is_rail, is_road, is_air) as
     ( select 1 id,'A','True','False','True'  from dual union all
       select 2 id,'A','False','False','True' from dual union all
       select 3 id,'A','True','False','False' from dual 
     )
select id
     , case when is_rail = 'True' then 1 else 0 end is_rail
     , case when is_road = 'True' then 1 else 0 end is_road
     , case when is_air  = 'True' then 1 else 0 end is_air     
  from port 
  where id = &p_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_port(p_id in port.id%type)
RETURN number
IS
transportation_count number;
port_status varchar2(10);
port_status_a varchar2(10);
port_status_b varchar2(10);
BEGIN
  Select is_rail into port_status from port where id=p_id;
  Select is_road into port_status_a from port where id=p_id;
  Select is_air into port_status_b from port where id=p_id;
IF port_status='True' 
THEN
   transportation_count:=transportation_count+1;
END IF;
  IF port_status_a='True' 
  THEN
   transportation_count:=transportation_count+1;
  END IF;
    IF port_status_b='True'
    THEN
     transportation_count:=transportation_count+1;
    END IF;
RETURN transportation_count;
END find_port;
/
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it's better to provide a brief explanation of the solution you provided,
so it may benefit the OP and future readers